# Extracting poly.counts through loops using R

Tags: r, loop

I want to extract the count of points over Africa at the first administrative district level at monthly intervals over 26 years. My point data consist of conflict events. I am struggling to figure out how to do this without spending a lifetime copy-pasting code.

I need to capture three things: the **country**, **administrative district name**, and the **count of events**.

My intuition is to use `poly.counts()` from `GISTools` in some sort of a loop, such as:

```
for(y in 1990:2016){
    for(m in 1:12){
       poly.counts(subset(data, year == y & month == m))
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to capture the output of each iteration into a single data frame. Ideally, this will produce a single data frame that shows the year, month, country, administrative district, and count. Below, I present a short "toy" version of what I want.

```
year     month     country     admin1     count
----     -----     --------    -------    ------
2003     1         Nigeria     Lagos      67
2003     1         Nigeria     Oyo        12
2003     1         Nigeria     Kaduna     54
2003     2         Nigeria     Lagos      12
2003     2         Nigeria     Oyo        24
2003     2         Nigeria     Kaduna     56
2003     3         Nigeria     Lagos      15
2003     3         Nigeria     Oyo        22
2003     3         Nigeria     Kaduna     14
```

Comment: As an alternative to the `table` recommendation you could also use `tapply`. Just another example of avoiding a for loop. A forewarning is that poly.counts cannot deal with a MULTI geometry type and would return erroneous results. In this case use a different function or explode the geometry into SINGLEPART.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `sf` package, if I have some polygons `nc`, each with a `NAME` field:

```
> head(nc)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -81.74107 ymin: 36.07282 xmax: -75.77316 ymax: 36.58965
epsg (SRID):    4267
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs
         NAME CNTY_ID                       geometry
1        Ashe    1825 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47276 3...
2   Alleghany    1827 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.23989 3...
3       Surry    1828 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45634 3...
```

and a set of points with `month` and `year` field:

```
> head(dp)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -83.10454 ymin: 34.15184 xmax: -76.22968 ymax: 36.43808
epsg (SRID):    4267
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs
  month year                   geometry
1     4 2009 POINT (-82.81116 34.46402)
2    12 2003 POINT (-78.08891 35.03015)
3     6 2010 POINT (-76.22968 34.15184)
```

then `st_intersection` will find the area each point is in (ignore warnings)

```
> pinter = st_intersection(dp, nc)
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar
Warning message:
attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all geometries 
> head(pinter)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 4 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -81.51732 ymin: 36.37807 xmax: -81.32702 ymax: 36.57252
epsg (SRID):    4267
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs
    month year NAME CNTY_ID                   geometry
49      1 2003 Ashe    1825   POINT (-81.516 36.52733)
318     1 2010 Ashe    1825 POINT (-81.51732 36.41511)
370    10 2005 Ashe    1825  POINT (-81.37002 36.3854)
```

Now I can tabulate that as I want. For example, total by month:

```
> table(pinter$month)

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12 
433 427 433 473 403 430 432 412 454 430 452 480
```

You seem to want total by year, month and region, which is a 3 dimensional table, but we can reduce that down to a data frame:

```
> head(data.frame(table(pinter$month, pinter$year, pinter$NAME)))
  Var1 Var2     Var3 Freq
1    1 2003 Alamance    1
2    2 2003 Alamance    0
3    3 2003 Alamance    1
4    4 2003 Alamance    1
5    5 2003 Alamance    0
6    6 2003 Alamance    0
```

This has all the zero counts as well, which if you don't want them you can subset from the data frame in the usual way.

If you don't want the zeroes, you can use `aggregate`:

```
> tab = aggregate(1:nrow(pinter), by=list(Month=pinter$month, Year=pinter$year, Name=pinter$NAME), FUN=length)
> head(tab)
  Month Year     Name x
1     1 2003 Alamance 1
2     3 2003 Alamance 1
3     4 2003 Alamance 1
4     7 2003 Alamance 1
```

(most of my data only has one point per month/year/region).

Comment: this is awesome! What is the format of the point data? I have mine in a SpatialPointsDataFrame. How can I transform it to work with this? Thank you.

Comment: You should look into a tutorial on the `sf` package. I think once you've installed and loaded that (`library(sf)`) then `X_sf = st_as_sf(X_sp)` will do a good job of converting an `sp` object to `sf`.

Comment: Cant you do `as(X_sp, "sf")` for coercion of sp feature classes to sf as well or is there an advantage of `st_as_sf`? I use this function in package functions so I am not relying on methods but is there an advantage of one over the other? I imagine that the `as` method is calling this function under the hood but I have not checked.

Comment: I prefer `st_as_sf` - you can't use `as(X,sf)` to convert a data frame, for example. With `st_as_sf` the documentation shows all the args and all the various things it can convert. I'm not a big fan of using `as` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on @Spacedman answer a bit. Say you wanted to aggregate a variable rather than return counts. This is where a function such as `tapply` comes in handy. You can do all of this

Here is some example data with the points feature calss having `month (1-5)`, `year (2000-2002)` and a random variable `x` as columns.

```
library(sf)  
nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
s <- st_as_sf(st_sample(nc, 500))
  s$month <- sample(1:5, 500,replace = TRUE)
  s$year <- sample(2000:2002, 500,replace = TRUE)
  s$y <- runif(500)
```

Now, we intersect the data and use `tapply` to calculate the mean of x for each year/month. I am using paste to concatenate month and year into a single aggregating factor. You can use this to get a counts a well but, the use of table is a bit more straightforward. You can do all of this with the aggregate function as well. In R there are often many ways of doing something.

```
a <- st_intersection(s, nc)
  tapply(s$y, paste(a$year, a$month,sep="/"), mean)
```